# Getting wrong answer for my submission for Bitmap in SPOJ

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am getting a Wrong Answer for my solution to Bitmap (http://www.spoj.com/problems/BITMAP/) in SPOJ.

Problem description: A matrix consisting of ONEs and ZEROs, where for each ZERO, we need to find the distance to the nearest ONE in the matrix. While measuring the distance between two points in the matrix, one can go UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT each by ONE unit.

The below solution passes for my test-cases. I'm not sure why it fails when I'm submitting it to the Judge, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define INF 9999999999

int main() {
    int T, M, N;
    cin >> T;

    vector<pair<int, int>> shift;
    shift.push_back(make_pair(0, -1));  // Left
    shift.push_back(make_pair(0, 1));   // Right
    shift.push_back(make_pair(1, 0));   // Down
    shift.push_back(make_pair(-1, 0));  // Up

    while ( T-- ) {
        cin >> M >> N;
        int arr[M][N];
        int result[M][N];
        memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));

        queue<pair<int, int>> q;
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
            string input;
            cin >> input;

            for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                result[i][j] = INF;
                arr[i][j] = input[j] - '0';
                if (arr[i][j]) {
                    q.push(make_pair(i, j));
                    result[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        q.push(make_pair(-1, -1));
        while (!q.empty()) {
            pair<int, int> p = q.front();
            q.pop();
            if (p.first == -1 && !q.empty()) { 
                q.push(make_pair(-1, -1));
            } else {
                for(int i=0; i<shift.size(); i++) {
                    if (p.first + shift[i].first >= 0 && p.first + shift[i].first < N &&
                        p.second + shift[i].second >= 0 && p.second + shift[i].second < N) {
                        if (!arr[p.first + shift[i].first][p.second + shift[i].second]) {
                             if (result[p.first + shift[i].first][p.second + shift[i].second] > 1 + result[p.first][p.second]) {
                                result[p.first + shift[i].first][p.second + shift[i].second] = 1 + result[p.first][p.second];
                                q.push(make_pair(p.first + shift[i].first, p.second + shift[i].second));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                cout << result[i][j];
                if (j<N-1) cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Resolving - typo for M instead of N.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake where 'M' was incorrectly typed as 'N'. Resolving the problem.